# Titanium appcelerator close automatically

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, android-sdk-2.3, titanium-modules

2 days ago I had installed Titanium Appcelerator 3.1 and today I installed android sdk 2.2 and 4.2, But now after starting my Titanium, it gets automatically closes after few minutes and showing some java related error.

My system configurations :

- Ubuntu 12.04
- 64 bit java 1.6.0_27
- Titanium 3.1
- Android sdk 2.2 and 4.2
- 4 GB RAM

Please find the error log below

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f29fb86f757, pid=2889, tid=139818259298048

 JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.3
 Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1
 Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x588757]  klassVtable::oop_follow_contents()+0xd7
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong JDK. You need to [use the OracleJDK as specified here.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Prerequisites-section-29004873_Prerequisites-JavaDevelopmentKit)